# Was sind Knochenscheiben?

Tags: meaning-in-context, context

»Geld soll aus Knochenscheiben gemacht sein, da es dann einem Verfallsprozess unterliegt und im Falle der Hortung so unerträglich zu stinken beginnt, dass es sehr bald weitergegeben wird.«

Was meint der Autor hier mit Geld soll aus Knochenscheiben gemacht sein ? ist das als Zeichnen fürs Alte des Gelds? oder was?